# Make a 2D legend for a plot - bi-variate choropleth maps

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gis

I have been playing with bi-variate choropleth maps and have gotten stuck on how to create a 2d legend similar to the one by [Joshua Stevens](http://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/) shown here:

[image]

To illustrate the challenge we don't need to use a map.  The code below will suffice:

```
#test desired legend appearance
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
#use color scheme shown here http://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/
bvColors=c("#be64ac","#8c62aa","#3b4994","#dfb0d6","#a5add3","#5698b9","#e8e8e8","#ace4e4","#5ac8c8")
legendGoal=melt(matrix(1:9,nrow=3))
test<-ggplot(legendGoal, aes(Var1,Var2))+ geom_tile(aes(fill = as.factor(value)))
test<- test + scale_fill_manual(name="Var1 vs Var2",values=bvColors,drop=FALSE)
test
```

It creates a plot that looks like the legend I am going for but of course the legend is a vertical bar of all the levels.  I want the legend to look like the plot itself.  Is there a way to do that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but I think you need to play with [guides](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/guide_legend.html).

```
ggplot(legendGoal, 
       aes(Var1,Var2,
           col=as.factor(value),
           fill=as.factor(value))) +
  geom_tile() +
  guides(col = guide_legend(nrow = 3))
```

[image]

Comment: Guides!  That's the ticket and an area of ggplot2 I hadn't explored.  Your solution is almost there. "col" as opposed to "fill" with guides precludes using manual colors in your example.  After blundering through some permutations I came up with the solution below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
#test desired legend appearance
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
#use color scheme shown here http://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/
bvColors=c("#be64ac","#8c62aa","#3b4994","#dfb0d6","#a5add3","#5698b9","#e8e8e8","#ace4e4","#5ac8c8")
melt(matrix(1:9,nrow=3))
legendGoal=melt(matrix(1:9,nrow=3))
test<-ggplot(legendGoal, aes(Var2,Var1,fill = as.factor(value)))+ geom_tile()
test<- test + scale_fill_manual(name="More Var2  -->",values=bvColors,drop=FALSE)
test<-test+guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 3))
test<-test + theme(legend.text=element_blank())

test
```

[image]

The only remaining trick is to find a way to add some vertical on the side of the legend saying "More Var1 -->." Here's a butt-ugly way to do it:

```
test<-ggplot(legendGoal, aes(Var2,Var1,fill = as.factor(value)))+ geom_tile()
test<- test + scale_fill_manual(name="More Var2  -->",values=bvColors,labels=c("","","","","","","More","Var 1"," v "))
test<-test+guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 3))
#test<-test + theme(legend.text=element_blank())

test
```

But, as zx shows, extending ggplot2 with the cowplot package is the complete solution:

```
#test desired legend appearance
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(reshape2)
#use color scheme shown here http://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/
bvColors=c("#be64ac","#8c62aa","#3b4994","#dfb0d6","#a5add3","#5698b9","#e8e8e8","#ace4e4","#5ac8c8")
melt(matrix(1:9,nrow=3))
legendGoal=melt(matrix(1:9,nrow=3))
test<-ggplot(legendGoal, aes(Var2,Var1,fill = as.factor(value)))+ geom_tile()
test<- test + scale_fill_manual(name="",values=bvColors)
test<-test+guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 3))
test<-test + theme(legend.text=element_blank())
test<-ggdraw(test) + draw_text(text = "More Var 2 -->",x=0.91,y=0.58)
test<-ggdraw(test) + draw_text(text = "More Var 1 -->",x=0.84,y=0.5,angle=270)
test
```

[image]

Just for fun this is the map that I made with this technique:
[image: NYC Pre-K Seats]

Answer (score 2):

Okay, last update.  The white space between columns bugs me and the grid feature of cowplot will let us use a shrunken plot as our bi-variate legend, like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(reshape2)
#use color scheme shown here http://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/
bvColors=c("#be64ac","#8c62aa","#3b4994","#dfb0d6","#a5add3","#5698b9","#e8e8e8","#ace4e4","#5ac8c8")
melt(matrix(1:9,nrow=3))
legendGoal=melt(matrix(1:9,nrow=3))
test<-ggplot(legendGoal, aes(Var2,Var1,fill = as.factor(value)))+ geom_tile()
test<- test + scale_fill_manual(name="",values=bvColors)
test<-test + theme(legend.position="none")
#test<-ggdraw(test) + draw_text(text = "More Var 2 -->",x=0.91,y=0.58)
#test<-ggdraw(test) + draw_text(text = "More Var 1 -->",x=0.84,y=0.5,angle=270)

#create a plot that will be the legend itself
lg<- test #would not be true when making a map
lg<-lg + theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=rel(1),color=bvColors[3])) + xlab("More Var2 -->")
lg<-lg + theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=rel(1),color=bvColors[3])) + ylab("More Var1 -->")
lg<-lg+theme(axis.text=element_blank())
lg<-lg+theme(line=element_blank())
#put both plots on a grid
ggdraw()+ draw_plot(lg,0.1,0.7,width=0.2,height=0.2) +draw_plot(test,0.3,0,width=.7,height=.7)
```

[image]
Pretty, yes?