# R - How can I add a bivariate legend to my ggplot2 chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to add a bivariate legend to my `ggplot2` chart but I don't know whether (a) this is possible through some `guides` options and (b) how to achieve it.

The only way I've managed to produce something close to the desired outcome was by specifically creating a new chart which resembles a legend (named `p.legend` below) and inserting it, via the `cowplot` package, somewhere in the original chart (named `p.chart` below). But surely there must be a better way than this, given that this approach requires creating the legend in the first place and fiddling with its size/location to fit it in the original chart.

Here's code for a dummy example of my approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create Dummy Data #
set.seed(876)
n <- 2
df <- expand.grid(Area = LETTERS[1:n],
                  Period = c("Summer", "Winter"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
      mutate(Objective = runif(2 * n, min = 0, max = 2),
             Performance = runif(2 * n) * Objective) %>% 
      gather(Type, Value, Objective:Performance)

# Original chart without legend #
p.chart <- df %>% 
            ggplot(., aes(x = Area)) + 
              geom_col(data = . %>% filter(Type == "Objective"),
                       aes(y = Value, fill = Period),
                       position = "dodge", width = 0.7, alpha = 0.6) + 
              geom_col(data = . %>% filter(Type == "Performance"),
                       aes(y = Value, fill = Period),
                       position = "dodge", width = 0.7) + 
              scale_fill_manual(values = c("Summer" = "#ff7f00", "Winter" = "#1f78b4"), guide = FALSE) + 
              theme_minimal() + 
              theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
                    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())

# Create a chart resembling a legend #
p.legend <- expand.grid(Period = c("Summer", "Winter"),
                        Type   = c("Objective", "Performance"),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
              ggplot(., aes(x = Period, y = factor(Type, levels = c("Performance", "Objective")),
                                                   fill = Period, alpha = Type)) + 
                geom_tile() + 
                scale_fill_manual(values = c("Summer" = "#ff7f00", "Winter" = "#1f78b4"), guide = FALSE) + 
                scale_alpha_manual(values = c("Objective" = 0.7, "Performance" = 1), guide = FALSE) + 
                ggtitle("Legend") + 
                theme_minimal() + 
                theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
                      rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
                      axis.title = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.major = element_blank())

# Add legend to original chart #
p.final <- cowplot::ggdraw() + 
                  cowplot::draw_plot(plot = p.chart) + 
                  cowplot::draw_plot(plot = p.legend, x = 0.5, y = 0.65, width = 0.4, height = 0.28, scale = 0.7)

# Save chart #
cowplot::ggsave("Bivariate Legend.png", p.final, width = 8, height = 6, dpi = 500)
```

... and the resulting chart:
[image: Chart with Bivariate Legend]

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: have you seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749889/make-a-2d-legend-for-a-plot-bi-variate-choropleth-maps)

Comment: Wow! I hadn't seen it, no. From what I see there, we are both using the "create-a-chart-looking-like-a-legend-and-adding-it-to-the-original-chart" method. But is there a way of achieving it directly through `ggplot2` (especially as that's a 3-year old post and functionality might have improved since then)?

Comment: You can probably do it with [the new `multiscales` package](https://github.com/clauswilke/multiscales)

Comment: Thanks @Axeman. I'll have a go with it and report back.

Answer (score 1):

This might work at some point, but right now the colorbox seems to ignore all breaks, names and labels (@ClausWilke?). Probably because the `multiscales` package is in really early stages.

Posting since it might work when future readers are here.

```
library(multiscales)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    period = as.numeric(factor(Period)),
    type = as.numeric(factor(Type))
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = Area, y = Value, fill = zip(period, type), group = interaction(Area, Period))) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.7, position = 'dodge') + 
  bivariate_scale(
    "fill", 
    pal_hue_sat(c(0.07, 0.6), c(0.4, 0.8)),
    guide = guide_colorbox(
      nbin = 2, 
      name = c("Period", "Type"),                       #ignored
      breaks = list(1:2, 1:2),                          #ignored
      labels = list(levels(.$Period), levels(.$Type))   #ignored
  )
```

[image]